# Spring Boot test - @Value is null when using test application.yaml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, junit4

I am trying to run a unit test with testing values in
**application.yaml** file, but I still receive **null** value into my **@Value** variable.

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { SpringBatchConfiguration.class })
public class WebServiceReaderTest {

    //some mock services here

    @InjectMocks
    private CustomWebServiceReader reader;

    private JobParameters jobParameters;

    @Test
    public void readerTest() throws Exception {
        StepExecution stepExecution = MetaDataInstanceFactory
                .createStepExecution(jobParameters);

        StepScopeTestUtils.doInStepScope(stepExecution, () -> reader.read());
    }

}
```

SpringBatchConfiguration.class

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SpringBatchConfiguration extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        // leave empty, so the spring batch will not use database, but a Map
    }
}
```

In my **Reader** class I am reading the value from property file.

```java
@Value("${data-import.threshold}")
private Long threshold;
```

I do have my **application.yaml** file in **src/test/resources** folder

```java
data-import:
    threshold: 10
```

I am using **Spring Boot 2.4.4** and **wiremock 2.27.2**.

I have tried using

```java
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { SpringBatchConfiguration.class }, initializers=
        ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer.class)
```

```java
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { SpringBatchConfiguration.class }, initializers=
        ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
```

```java
@TestPropertySource(locations = { "classpath:application.yaml" })
```

but none of these worked.

Comment: ofcourse it is `null` `@InjectMocks` will create a new instance using Mockito. INsteadyou should use `@Autowired` to get the Spring configured instance.

Comment: It says I don't have a Bean of CustomWebServiceReader. It has a JobScope and Component annotation.

Comment: Remove `@ContextConfiguration`.

Comment: When I remove it, it doesn't run the test but the whole application (triggers RabbitMQ listener etc.).

Comment: COrrect that is what `@SpringBootTest` is supposed to do.

Comment: Great, but if I remove both the `@SpringBootTest` and `@ContextConfiguration`, the properties are still null.

Comment: Ofcourse they will as `@INjectMocks` will just create a new instance using Mockito, that already renders all of that spring config useless.